# How do you edit an f curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I added a noise f-curve modifier to a graph, but it's too jittery. How can I lower the amplitude and frequency of the noise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Graph Editor*, select the track to which you've given a Noise (example: *X Location*), press <kbd>N</kbd> to display the properties panel, choose the *Modifiers* tab, and play with the *Scale* and *Strength* values. Is it what you want?

[image]